# Call a method within a React Component from Electron's globalShortcut

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have a React component with a method:

```
class Timer extends Component{

  start(){
    this.timerInterval=setInterval(this.tick,1000);
  }

  [...]
}
```

I want to be able to call the method start() whenever the user presses a combination of keys. 
In my main.js file I have:

```
 app.on('ready', function(){
      createWindow();
      globalShortcut('Cmd+Alt+K',function(){
        //call start() here 
      })
    });
```

How can I achieve this? There's not much information I could find on this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in need of use of electron library inside react you should import it using electron remote

```
const { globalShortcut } = require('electron').remote;

class Timer extends Component{
     componentDidMount = () => {

    globalShortcut.register('Cmd+Alt+K', () => {
      //your call
      this.start()
    });
}

  start(){
    this.timerInterval=setInterval(this.tick,1000);
  }

  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping someone with Electron-specific experience would address this, but it's been a full day now.

To cross the outside world / React component barrier, you're probably best off using a custom event. To do that, you'll need access to the DOM element created by React in response to your `render` call, then listen for your custom event directly on the element. Here's an example, see the comments for details. Note that in this example I'm passing an object as the event detail; that's just to show you can do that (not just simple strings), but you could just do `{detail: "Tick #" + ticker}` instead and use `event.detail` directly as the message.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  // Normal component setup
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {message: ""};

    // Our event handler. (We could also define this at the class level using the class
    // fields syntax that's currently at Stage 3 in the ECMA TC39 process; most React
    // setups with JSX transpile class fields syntax.)
    this.doSomething = event => {
      this.setState({message: event.detail.message || ""});
    };
  }

  // Render with a way of finding the element in the DOM from outside (in this case
  // I'm using a class, but it could be an ID, or just knowing where it is in the DOM).
  // We use a ref so we can hook the event when the elemet is created.
  render() {
    return <div className="foo" ref={element => this.element = element}>{this.state.message}</div>;
  }

  // Hook the event on mount, unhook it on unmount
  componentDidMount() {
    this.element.addEventListener("my-event", this.doSomething);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.element.removeEventListener("my-event", this.doSomething);
  }
}

// Top-level app rendering
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));

// Demonstrate triggering the event, in our case we do it every half-second or so
let ticker = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  const foo = document.querySelector("#root .foo");
  ++ticker;
  foo.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("my-event", {detail: {message: "Tick #" + ticker}}));
}, 500);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```